# Prevent mousewheel from scrolling past elements

Tags: mousewheel

I have a wrapper div which includes several children all of which are 100%/100vh height. I want the scrollwheel to stop at each child element so that the user won't be able to use the mousewheel to scroll at the end of the page bypassing some of the child elements.

Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try scroll-snap-type and scroll-snap-stop:always but im not sure if you are looking for that or to completely disable scrolling at certain child element.

Comment: I have already implemented the .css properties you have mentioned and it works if you scroll gently up and down or use the up and down arrows on the keyboard. If scroll a lot though the scroll snapping is ignored and the parent div scrolls to the bottom of the page skipping all the other elements.